# Inefficient SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, mysqli

I'm building a simple web app at the moment that I'll one day open source. As it stands at the moment, the nav is generated on every page load (which will change to be cached one day) but for the moment, it's being made with the code below. Using PHP 5.2.6 and MySQLi 5.0.7.7, how more efficient can the code below be? I think joins might help, but I'm after advice. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    $navQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,slug,name FROM categories WHERE live=1 ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    while($nav = $navQuery->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="/'. $nav->slug .'">'. $nav->name .'</a>';
            echo '<ul>';
                $subNavQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,name FROM snippets WHERE category='$nav->id' ORDER BY name ASC") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                while($subNav = $subNavQuery->fetch_object()) {
                    echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="/'. $nav->slug .'/'. $subNav->name .'">'. $subNav->name .'</a>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: +1 for posting this question; loops with queries in them are bad bad bad. I'm not good enough with JOINs to help you out, but there are many others who are!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run this query:

```
SELECT c.id AS cid, c.slug AS cslug, c.name AS cname,
    s.id AS sid, s.name AS sname
FROM categories AS c
    LEFT JOIN snippets AS s ON s.category = c.id
WHERE c.live=1
ORDER BY c.name, s.name
```

Then iterate thru the results to create the proper heading like:

```
// last category ID
$lastcid = 0;
while ($r = $navQuery->fetch_object ()) {

    if ($r->cid != $lastcid) {
        // new category

        // let's close the last open category (if any)
        if ($lastcid)
            printf ('</li></ul>');

        // save current category
        $lastcid = $r->cid;

        // display category
        printf ('<li><a href="/%s">%s</a>', $r->cslug, $r->cname);

        // display first snippet
        printf ('<li><a href="/%s/%s">%s</a></li>', $r->cslug, $r->sname, $r->sname);

    } else {

        // category already processed, just display snippet

        // display snippet
        printf ('<li><a href="/%s/%s">%s</a></a>', $r->cslug, $r->sname, $r->sname);
    }
}

// let's close the last open category (if any)
if ($lastcid)
    printf ('</li></ul>');
```

Note that I used `printf` but you should use your own function instead which wraps around printf, but runs `htmlspecialchars` thru the parameters (except the first of course).

Disclaimer: I do not necessarily encourage such use of `<ul>`s.

This code is just here to show the basic idea of processing hierarchical data got with one query.

Comment: Had to jiggle the UL & LI tags, but the theory was perfect. The nav now loads between 2 and 3 times faster. Thanks, Bence! :)

Comment: why does this question have a bounty?

Comment: @JohnP I'm interested in other (maybe better) solutions. I posted two aproaches, but both of them have shortcomings too. I'm really interested if there are even more ways.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you shouldn't query your database in your view. That would be mixing your business logic and your presentation logic. Just assign the query results to a variable in your controller and iterate through it.

As for the query, yup a join can do that in 1 query.

```
SELECT * -- Make sure you only select the fields you want. Might need to use aliases to avoid conflict
FROM snippets S LEFT JOIN categiries C ON S.category = C.id
WHERE live = 1
ORDER BY S.category, C.name
```

This will get you an initial result set. But this won't give you the data nicely ordered like you expect. You'll need to use a bit of PHP to group it into some arrays that you can use in your loops.

Something along the lines of

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
   $snippet = array();
   //assign all the snippet related data into this var

  if (isset($categories[$result['snippets.category']])) {

    $categories[$result['snippets.category']]['snippet'][] = $snippet;
  } else {
    $category = array();
    //assign all the category related data into this var;

    $categories[$result['snippets.category']]['snippet']  = array($snippet);
    $categories[$result['snippets.category']]['category'] = $category;
  }
}
```

This should give you an array of categories which have all the related snippets in an array. You can simply loop through this array to reproduce your list.

Comment: MVC is not the only possible way.

Comment: yup, but it's always a good idea to have your data layer separate.

Comment: Not neccesarily. You always have to consider the pros and cons. In this case there is a query with an HTML output, the whole thing takes 5 minutes to write, you can throw it away any time without much heartache. In return you get a code without any abstraction layers and additional memory footprint which will run every time your page loads. Also adding to the equation the probability of this part of DB to change, it can make the case in favor of lightweight "expendbale" code. - Needless to say I'm not against abstraction layers, but they are not necessarily needed *in every case*.

Comment: @vbence Your assumption that this part of the code is standalone is pretty dangerous. OP clearly states he's building a web app. Exactly the type of project that would benefit. `..adding to the equation the probability of this part of DB to change..` exactly the reason that you _should_ have an abstract. Otherwise you end up going through all your pages just because the order changed or something trivial like that.

Comment: It seems to me like a pretty general menu structure which could work for many different projects. But only the OP has enough information to make this decision.

Comment: I'm still in the early stages of learning frameworks like CodeIgniter & FuelPHP. In retrospect, I should've waited until I'm more comfortable with frameworks to build this, but y'know what we devs are like, need to bash out that code & refine later.

Comment: @PaulAdamDavis No, no and no. You absolutely have to create a project with php's "native" tools before you use any kind of framework. Then when something goes wrong you will know what goes on in the background.

Comment: It depends. If your project is needed to be scalable enough, then MVC would be more suitable not to screw up things in future, else if just making up several static HTML pages without sclability concerns, then all in one scripts would be another quick and dirty solution.

Comment: I personally agree with the solution of @JohnP but one thing I'm missing is that nobody suggested to use proper indexes for the columns, thus far be sure to set indexes at columns live, and category,  @PaulAdamDavis also keep in mind if you make a join that the sequence of the columns you use for the join must match the sequence of the columns in the index defintion

Comment: I agree with @vbence - if you're building it for yourself, learn from the root of the language.  But if you're building it for someone else, in this day and age, use a framework :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this one:

```
SELECT
    c.slug,c.name,s.name
FROM
    categories c
LEFT JOIN snippets s
    ON s.category = c.id 
WHERE live=1 ORDER BY c.name, s.name
```

I didnt test it, though. Also check the indexes using the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) statement so MySQL doesnt do a full scan of the table.

With these results, you can loop the results in PHP and check when the category name changes, and build your output as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Besides a single combined query you can use two separate ones.

You have a basic tree-structure here with branch elements (categories table) and leaf elements (snippets table). The shortcoming of the single-query solution is that you get owner brach-element repeatedly for every single leaf element. This is redundant information and depending on the number of leafs and the amount of information you query from each branch element can produce large amount of additional traffic.

The two-query solution looks like:

```
$navQuery = $mysqli->query ("SELECT id, slug, name FROM categories WHERE live=1 ORDER BY name")
    or die (mysqli_error ($mysqli));
$subNavQuery = $mysqli->query ("SELECT c.id AS cid, s.id, s.name FROM categories AS c LEFT JOIN snippets AS s ON s.category=c.id WHERE c.live=1 ORDER BY c.name, s.name")
    or die (mysqli_error ($mysqli));

$sub = $subNavQuery->fetch_object ();    // pre-reading one record
while ($nav = $navQuery->fetch_object ()) {

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="/'. $nav->slug .'">'. $nav->name .'</a>';
    echo '<ul>';

    while ($sub->cid == $nav->id) {

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="/'. $nav->slug .'/'. $sub->name .'">'. $sub->name .'</a>';
        echo '</li>';

        $sub = $subNavQuery->fetch_object ();
    } 

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should print completely the same code as your example

```
$navQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT t1.id AS cat_id,t1.slug,t1.name AS cat_name,t2.id,t2.name
    FROM categories AS t1
    LEFT JOIN snippets AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.category
    WHERE t1.live=1
    ORDER BY t1.name ASC, t2.name ASC") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$current = false;

while($nav = $navQuery->fetch_object()) {
    if ($current != $nav->cat_id) {
        if ($current) echo '</ul>';
        echo '<a href="/'. $nav->slug .'">'. $nav->cat_name .'</a><ul>';
        $current = $nav->cat_id;
    }

    if ($nav->id) { //check for empty category
        echo '<li><a href="/'. $nav->slug .'/'. $nav->name .'">'. $nav->name .'</a></li>';
    }
}

//last category
if ($current) echo '</ul>';
```