# Change SQL query to show categories that are empty

Tags: sql

A while ago, I asked for help on [this SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529546/inefficient-sql-query). It shows snippets that belong to a parent category, using the category ID to tie them together. I tried to change it to show all categories, even when there's no snippets inside but I can't manage it.

I am sure this is not a PHP thing, as printing the result of this query does not show empty categories.

I just need help understanding this and what I need to change to make it show what I need it to.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT c.id AS cid, c.slug AS cslug, c.name AS cname, s.id AS sid, s.name AS sname 
FROM categories AS c 
LEFT JOIN snippets AS s ON s.category = c.id 
WHERE c.live=1 AND s.live=1 AND c.company='$company' AND s.company='$company' 
ORDER BY c.name, s.name
```

Any tips and links to good resources to learn SQL would be appreciated too. :)

Here's an example of what the query returns when run through PHP. SQL http://jsbin.com/obonal PHP [Inefficient SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529546/inefficient-sql-query#answer-5529624)

Comment: Can you post an example result?

Comment: Edited my OP with SQL & PHP examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the snippet condition into the `on` clause of the join.

If you leave it in the `where` clause, result rows are required to match it, but missing rows from snippet will have `null` values, so `s.live=1` will be `false` and you'll get no match.

In the on clause, only rows from snippet are required to match it, but with the `left`, matching is optional so you still get row from categories when snippet doesn't match:

```
SELECT c.id AS cid, c.slug AS cslug, c.name AS cname, s.id AS sid, s.name AS sname 
FROM categories AS c 
LEFT JOIN snippets AS s ON s.category = c.id AND s.live=1 AND s.company='$company' 
WHERE c.company='$company'
AND c.live=1 
ORDER BY c.name, s.name
```

The key part is the `join on` clause, which can be arbitrarily complex, and in the example of `s.live=1` do not have to be true "join" predicates (ie don't have to compare values between tables - they can be just tests on the row itself):

```
LEFT JOIN snippets AS s ON s.category = c.id AND s.live=1 AND s.company='$company'
```

Note that some databases, eg mysql, allow your original syntax to still work as desired.

**EDITED** Moved s.company='$company' into the on clause too. Thanks @Andriy

Comment: I agree with with how you've summarised the core of the issue, but the WHERE clause in your query is in fact still containing a condition for the right-side table (`s.company='$company'`).

Comment: @Andriy Oh - didn't notice that. I'll move that in too!

Comment: Thanks, Bohemian and @Andriy. The query now works how I need it to and I know how! Cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

With RIGHT JOIN do you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the perfect match you need an Inner Join. If you want all the rows from the left and all the rows from the right and left with the same id you need a Left Join.